# How to use custom dataset in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I have started learning tensorflow recently. I am trying to input my custom python code as training data. I have generated random exponential signals and want the network to learn from that. This is the code I am using for generating signal-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np

lorange= 1
hirange= 10
amplitude= random.uniform(-10,10)
t= 10
random.seed()
tau=random.uniform(lorange,hirange)
x=np.arange(t)

plt.xlabel('t=time")
plt.ylabel('x(t)')
plt.plot(x, amplitude*np.exp(-x/tau))
plt.show()
```

How can I use this graph as input vector in tensorflow?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `tf.placeholder` function ([see the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholders)):

```
# Your input data
x = np.arange(t)
y = amplitude*np.exp(-x/tau)

# Create a corresponding tensorflow node
x_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(t,))
y_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(t,))
```

You can then use x_node and y_node in your tensorflow code (for instance use `x_node` as the input of a neural network and try to predict `y_node`).
Then when using `sess.run()` you have to feed the input data `x` and `y` with a `feed_dict` argument:

```
with tf.Session() as sess: 
    sess.run([...], feed_dict={x_node: x, y_node: y})
```